# cakephp phpunit test single controler ok but KO whith full test

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

with cakephp 4.4.2, I have this test:

```
public function testVindex(): void
{
    $method = '/historiques/vindex';

    // Not connected
    
    $this->get($method);
    $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);

}
```

It works fine when I just test this controller with:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit  tests/TestCase/Controller/HistoriquesControllerTest.php
```

But when this test is done with the others, with :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This generates an error:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\HistoriquesControllerTest::testVindex
Possibly related to Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthenticatedException: "No identity found." 
...
Failed asserting that response has header 'Location'.

/opt/applications2/p35/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestTrait.php:839
/opt/applications2/p35/tests/TestCase/Controller/HistoriquesControllerTest.php:53

--
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: There's like a thousand possible reasons, it's impossible to really tell without seeing all the related code. Seemingly it has something to do with authentication and possibly state being kept between tests. Remove/comment your other tests until things start working, or the other way around, remove everything else and re-add the other tests until things start failing, this should eventually lead you to the conflict.

Comment: thanks mdm I will try to isolate groups of tests with @groups to investigate

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, there was a side effect with an other test.

The other test need to simulate an ajax request, in order to do that:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; 

$this->get('/contests/synthese');
$this->assertResponseOk();
$this->assertHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$this->assertContentType('application/json');
```

To correct the problem, I just have to :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = ''
```

at the end of the test

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't touch superglobals directly when using CakePHP. In your test you should use `configRequest()` to set the `X-Requested-With` header, see **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#setting-up-the-request**, this will be properly isolated from other tests. Similarly in your application you should never read from `$_SERVER`, but from the request object.

Comment: thanks @ndm, it's the right way to do it